# Select specific columns with a condition in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

lets say that i have user table that has many users in it. I want to get all users but not the auth user. How can i do that in a simple query?, i tried:

```
$users = User::whereNotIn('id',auth()->user()->id)->get();
```

But it didn't work. Any help please? and sorry for this simple question.

Comment: read laravel docs , do some  research before posing questions directly https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#basic-where-clauses

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`In` and `NotIn` need an array as second args

```
$users = User::whereNotIn('id',[auth()->id()])->get();
```

for more : https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-wherenotin

Answer (score 0):

As `auth()->id()` will return single value not an array. So you should use

```
$users = User::where('id', '!=', auth()->id())->get();
```